# Convert *.csv file in DB with repeat second header several times

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have *.csv file that looks:

```
# time;P_O2, atm;P_He, atm;Flow O2, l/min;Flow He, l/min;FiO2 Env, %;FiO2 sens2, %;P mask, cm H2O;Tmask, gradC;Tnagr, gradC;V, ml;f, 1/min;Tzad, gradC;FiO2 zad, %;Flags;
# POWERON 01.11.2018 15:02:29
1;39;33;0;2;0;0;255;135;135;0;0;0;25;83886592;0
5;39;33;0;2;0;0;255;135;135;0;0;0;25;83886624;0
26;0;0;0;8;529;0;255;135;135;0;0;0;25;83886592;0
72;0;0;0;8;598;0;248;135;135;0;0;0;25;83886085;0
# POWERON 01.11.2018 15:04:02
1;0;0;0;7;0;0;255;135;135;0;0;0;25;83886592;0
2;0;0;0;7;113;0;255;135;135;0;0;0;25;83886085;0
# POWERON 01.11.2018 15:04:48
1;0;0;0;6;0;0;255;135;135;0;0;0;25;83886592;0
2;0;0;0;6;115;0;255;135;135;0;0;0;25;83886085;0
```

So, I try convert it to DB and make this one:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')

stud_data = pd.read_csv(r'Log/20181101.LOG', sep=';', engine='python')
stud_data.to_sql('interation', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
cur = conn.cursor()
for row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM interation'):
    print(row)
conn.close()
```

but my result is:

```
('# POWERON 01.11.2018 15:02:29', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
('1', 39.0, 33.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 135.0, 135.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 83886592.0, 0.0)
('5', 39.0, 33.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 135.0, 135.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 83886624.0, 0.0)
('26', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 529.0, 0.0, 255.0, 135.0, 135.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 83886592.0, 0.0)
('72', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 598.0, 0.0, 248.0, 135.0, 135.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 83886085.0, 0.0)
('# POWERON 01.11.2018 15:04:02', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
('1', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 135.0, 135.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 83886592.0, 0.0)
('2', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 113.0, 0.0, 255.0, 135.0, 135.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 83886085.0, 0.0)
('# POWERON 01.11.2018 15:04:48', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
('1', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0, 135.0, 135.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 83886592.0, 0.0)
```

I need value (date) in 'POWERON' insert second columns each other iteration like this:

```
POWERON;                 time; P_O2, atm; P_He, atm; ....

01.11.2018 15:02:29      1;    39;        33;   ...

01.11.2018 15:02:29      5;    39;        33;   ...
```

How I may do it simple? May be with pd.read_csv (some option?) or I must use some iteration on DB?
It's my first question, sorry for any mistakes design errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.read_csv` is not sufficient to extract the datetime in comments. You have to parse the csvfile yourself. Furthermore, the number of column of header and data are unbalanced.

```
import sqlite3
import io

def load_csvfile(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as csvfile:
        data = io.StringIO()
        line = csvfile.readline()
        line = f"POWERON;{line.rsplit(';', 1)[0]}\n"
        data.writelines([line])
        for line in csvfile.readlines():
            if line.startswith('# POWERON'):
                dt = line[10:].strip()
            else:
                line = f"{dt};{line.rsplit(';', 1)[0]}\n"
                data.writelines([line])
    data.seek(0)
    return pd.read_csv(data, sep=';', parse_dates=['POWERON'])

conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')

stud_data = load_csvfile(r'Log/20181101.LOG')
stud_data.to_sql('interation', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
cur = conn.cursor()
for row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM interation'):
    print(row)
conn.close()
```

```
('2018-01-11 15:02:29', 1, 39, 33, 0, 2, 0, 0, 255, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 25, 83886592)
('2018-01-11 15:02:29', 5, 39, 33, 0, 2, 0, 0, 255, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 25, 83886624)
('2018-01-11 15:02:29', 26, 0, 0, 0, 8, 529, 0, 255, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 25, 83886592)
('2018-01-11 15:02:29', 72, 0, 0, 0, 8, 598, 0, 248, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 25, 83886085)
('2018-01-11 15:04:02', 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 255, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 25, 83886592)
('2018-01-11 15:04:02', 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 113, 0, 255, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 25, 83886085)
('2018-01-11 15:04:48', 1, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 255, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 25, 83886592)
('2018-01-11 15:04:48', 2, 0, 0, 0, 6, 115, 0, 255, 135, 135, 0, 0, 0, 25, 83886085)
```

Note: you will receive an UserWarning about the spaces in column names.

Comment: I did it, thanks, but my header delete too and date in 'POWERON' delete too. I need insert date in 'POWERON' first column in DB and save my header.

Comment: Length of values and headers mismatch. You have 15 fields (semi colon separated) on header and each line of data has 16 fields. How to fix that?

Comment: You right! I don's see that. Wait a sometime please, I must find answer for this note.

Comment: Each line of date must contains 15 elements. Last element need to delete.